# SQL Combine Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Having trouble combining tables in a SQL join.  I would like to combine both table A column of NationalAvg and table B column SchoolAvg in table C however none of my queries are correct.

Table A - Where I can get NationalAvg

```
 Select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as NationalAvg, e.exams_description
from members_exams as me
left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
where me.members_exams_score is not null
group by e.exams_description
```

Results

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|NationalAvg         | exams_description |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| .78                | Medical Asst.Exam |
| .90                | Health Exam       |
| .79                | EKG Exam          |
| .81                | Phlebotomy        |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Table B - Where I can get SchoolAvg

```
select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as SchoolAvg, e.exams_description, s.schools_name
from members_exams as me
left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
where me.members_exams_score is not null
group by e.exams_description, s.schools_name
order by s.schools_name
```

Results

```
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|SchoolAvg           | exams_description |  School      |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------
| .90                | Medical Asst.Exam | School A     |
| .88                | Health Exam       | School A     |
| .65                | EKG Exam          | School A     |
| .76                | Phlebotomy        | School A     |
| .93                | Medical Asst.Exam | School B     |
| .79                | Health Exam       | School B     |
| .82                | EKG Exam          | School B     |
| .76                | Phlebotomy        | School B     |
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Incorrect Combine Table - Wanting Both SchoolAvg & NationalAvg.  The NationalAvg column is not showing up.

```
select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2)  as SchoolAvg, e.exams_description, s.schools_name
from members_exams as me
left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
join 
        ( select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as NationalAvg
        from members_exams as me
        left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
        join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
        group by e.exams_description) nAvg on e.exams_id = nAvg.NationalAvg
where me.members_exams_score is not null
group by  s.schools_name, e.exams_description
```

Results - are bring back the same table as B.
Intended Results -

```
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+
|  School Avg      |NationalAvg         | exams_description |  School      |
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------|
| .90              | .78                | Medical Asst.Exam | School A     |
| .88              | .90                | Health Exam       | School A     |
| .65              | .79                | EKG Exam          | School A     |
| .76              | .81                | Phlebotomy        | School A     |
| .93              | .78                | Medical Asst.Exam | School B     |
| .79              | .90                | Health Exam       | School B     |
| .82              | .79                | EKG Exam          | School B     |
| .76              | .81                | Phlebotomy        | School B     |
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your logic to CTEs and joining that way.

```
With CTE1 as(
  Select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as NationalAvg, e.exams_description
  from members_exams as me
  left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
  join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
  where me.members_exams_score is not null
  group by e.exams_description
),CTE2 as (
  select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as SchoolAvg, e.exams_description, s.schools_name
  from members_exams as me
  left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
  join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
  where me.members_exams_score is not null
  group by e.exams_description, s.schools_name
)
select A.exams_description, A.NationalAvg, B.schools_name, B.SchoolAvg
from CTE A
left Join CTE1 B ON A.exams_description = B.exams_description
```

Comment: Awesome news to hear @Jay!! Thanks for accepting that solution

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your input-output examples, you want to join the two tables on the column exams_description.

Since you already have two subqueries written yourself, you can do a join on the result of the two subqueries.

```
with T1 as(
  select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as NationalAvg, e.exams_description
  from members_exams as me
  left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
  join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
  where me.members_exams_score is not null
  group by e.exams_description
),T2 as (
  select Round(Cast(AVG(me.members_exams_score)as float), 2) as SchoolAvg, e.exams_description, s.schools_name
  from members_exams as me
  left join exams as e on e.exams_id = me.exams_id
  join schools as s on s.schools_id = me.schools_id
  where me.members_exams_score is not null
  group by e.exams_description, s.schools_name
)
select T2.SchoolAvg, T1.NationalAvg, T2.exams_description, T1.exams_description
from T1 Join T2
where T1.examples_description = T2.examples_description;
```